# Mind-boggling results of a simple query

Tags: sql, .net, oledb, visual-foxpro

Not sure how to explain it, unless this is a bug. I'm using VFP OLEDB driver to connect to a DBF database and trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT id FROM MyDBF WHERE (id > 21800) AND (id < 21820)
```

I get the following results (copying them on one line to save space):

```
21810, 21811, 21812, 21813, 21814, 21815, 21816, 21817, 21818, 21819
```

Now I change the query slightly:

```
SELECT id FROM MyDBF WHERE (id > 21810) AND (id < 21820)
```

You expect it to return all of the IDs from previous result except the first one. Booo! The query doesn't return any rows.

Just to make sure I'm not sleepy, I run the following query

```
SELECT id FROM MyDBF WHERE (id = 21817)
```

Should return a row, but it doesn't. Not sure what's going on. I have checked the field type and it is `OleDbType.Numeric`.

So is this me or MS?

Comment: How are you running the query - can you paste code? Are you sure you have closed your datareader? If you run the first query again do you get the same 10 records?

Comment: @robnick: To exclude any issues caused by the code, I'm running these directly through Database Explorer (this is VS2013 Express for Desktop btw, the tool window was known as Server Explorer in VS2010 and earlier). So no code issues.

Comment: Also OleDbType.Numeric maps to Decimal - this seems odd for an Id? It doesn't explain why the second SELECT doesn't work...?

Comment: Did you try BETWEEN clause?

Comment: @Oleg: Yes, same results.

Comment: IMO this could be because of decimals in the ID field. Try to "play" with the following construction `WHERE (id = 21817.00)`, or transfrom ID field to _Integer_.

Comment: @Oleg: Some more findings: The results get corrupted once my query range is above 20210. Before that, all works well. Also, the exact field in foxpro is `Numeric (7, 0)`.

Comment: Try to change ID field type: set it _Integer_, and then _Numeric(9,0)_.

Comment: @Oleg: I don't have the luxury to change the structure of foxpro database. All I can do must be done at query level. How do I cast it to Integer? Normal CAST and CONVERT operators don't appear to work with VFP OLEDB.

Comment: @Oleg: OK, some light. using `INT(id) = 21817` instead of `id = 21817` appears to work. mmm... so this is probably a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting the workaround I found here to help any future readers. Many thanks to Oleg for his helping hand.

Using `INT(id) = 21817` instead of `id = 21817` appears to work. Other versions of the SQL statement such as `INT(id) BETWEEN x AND y` and `INT(id) > x AND INT(id) < y` also appear to work fine. There's probably some discrepancy between the `NUMERIC` data type of FoxPro and the way OLEDB driver treats it.